# ubuntu npm related questions

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, npm

I installed npm and node via command 
`brew install node` successfully. And the terminal showed the version of npm and node when I typed in `node -v` and `npm -v`.

However, when I tried to install Karma via `sudo npm install -g karma`, the terminal showed `npm:command not found`. And I turned to `/usr/bin`, there was no npm there.

What's wrong with my installation? Thanks!

Comment: It is possible that you are not having /usr/local/bin in your PATH variable

Do you get anything if you use this:
/usr/local/bin/npm

You should get some messages related to how to use npm. If so, then try the following:
export PATH = $PATH:/usr/local/bin

then try npm install --production again.

Comment: open a new terminal and check it again